# terser removes the function

Tags: javascript, minify, terser

I am using terser to compress my code. But it turns out that it removes a function that is called only in html code (I understand that I set module: true)

I also set dead_code: false to keep unreachable code from being removed, but that didn't change anything at all, the function is still removed

What should I do?

Here are my options:

```
{
        compress: {
            drop_console: true,
            drop_debugger: false,
            dead_code: false,
        },
        mangle: {
            reserved: ["getUserStats"],
        },
        module: true,
        toplevel: true,
        keep_fnames: false
    }
```

Even when I call the function in another file that is also used in minification, the function is removed. What the hell???

Comment: So you're defining this function in the global scope to be accessible by your HTML. Have you considered using JavaScript to attach this function to your HTML? (it's an event handler I'm assuming). That way Terser will see that your function is in fact being used.

Comment: I'm using Laravel and calling a function in a template engine, putting it in the right place as @section('scripts')
     <script>getUserStats("123");</script>
@endsection
Maybe that's why Terser doesn't see her. But why doesn't the dead_code: false parameter work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did this and it worked:

```
function myFunc(){}

window.myFunc = myFunc;
```